# bash script check input argument

Tags: bash, shell

Today, I have to check the existence and the number of input arguments. I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "*** Test ***"
echo
echo $#
echo $*

function test1(){
   echo "test"
}

function GetTime()
{
   echo "Get Time function"
   if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
       echo "Illegal number of parameters"
   else
       test1
   fi
}

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Illegal number of parameters"
else
    test1
    GetTime  
fi
```

When I enter ./test.sh GetTime I get

```
*** Test ***

1
GetTime
test
Get Time function
Illegal number of parameters
```

I do not understand why the behavior is different between the first condition and the one contains within the GetTime() function. Somebody could help me ?

Thank in advance

Comment: Have you missed posting some of your script?  How is `GetTime()` even being called?

Comment: Since when are bash functions defined using a function keyword?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is different because `$#` in first `if` refer to the number of arguments to the shell script. Where as the `$#` in second indicates the number of argument to `GetTime` function

To understand more I have modified the `GetTime` function as

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "*** Test ***"
echo
echo $#
echo $*

function test1(){
   echo "test"
}

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Illegal number of parameters"
else
    test1   
fi

function GetTime()
{
   echo "Get Time function"
   echo "$# $@"
   if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
       echo "Illegal number of parameters"
   else
       test1
   fi
}

GetTime 
GetTime 2
```

Giving output as

```
*** Test ***
1
GetTime
test
Get Time function
0 
Illegal number of parameters
Get Time function
1 2
test
```

Here for the first call `GetTime` gives

```
Get Time function
0 
Illegal number of parameters
```

Where `0` is the number of parameters passed

and Second call as `GetTime 2`

produced output

```
Get Time function
1 2
test
```

Where `1` is the number of parameters passed and `2` is the argument itself

Comment: But `GetTime()` isn't getting called anywhere.

Comment: @anubhava Op might have missed it. I dont think the output is obtainable without a call to `GetTime()`